# Pruning large amount of stale records in Neptune

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am following the best practices of pruning stale data from our Neptune Graph Database seen below.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/best-practices-gremlin-prune.html

`g.V().has('timestamp', lt(datetime('2021-02-23'))).drop()`

This works fine on small datasets, but my graph generates about a million vertices a day. Am I supposed to have a service running continuously just dropping vertices in batches like below? What's the best approach for pruning large datasets?

```
while (pruneCount > 0):
   g.V().has('timestamp', lt(datetime('2021-02-23'))).limit(1000).drop()
   pruneCount = g.V().has('timestamp', lt(datetime('2021-02-23'))).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to drop say a million vertices, one strategy that I find works is to retrieve the ID's of all the vertices (and edges) that you need to drop and then drop them in batches across multiple threads. In this way you can drop 1M elements fairly efficiently. It's generally best to drop the edges before you drop the vertices to avoid possible concurrent modification exceptions if two threads are trying to drop two adjacent vertices.

You may be able to adapt the algorithm used here to your purposes: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/drop-graph